# CardView corners not rounded in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, rounded-corners, android-cardview

I'm creating an `AlertDialog` and the custom layout for that dialog is a `CardView` (the card is the root of the xml layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/moreInfoCard"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    //my layout content

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

When I show the dialog the card has its corners rounded, but the background of the corners it's not transparent.

[image]

How can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: try with `alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);`

Comment: @Blackbelt : It should posted as an answer

Answer (score 31, accepted):

call `alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transpare‌​nt);` to set the `AlertDialog`'s background to transparent and it will work

Comment: But this does not allow to set a margin of the root

Comment: why doesn't ? What it does is chaining a background ? How is it related to *margin* ? @Merian

Comment: I really can get why but when I try to add a margin on a cardview it does not apply, and than after I comment this line for background the margin is working properly